# Sequelize - Inserting date always returns null?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to test posting dates via Postman into my database.

My model is setup as below. I destructured { Date } from Sequelize hence it only says Date.

```
eventDate: {
  type: DATE,
},
```

I've been posting dates in different formats via Postman, and they all return null. I'm not entirely sure if there is something else I have to define in the model?

```
"eventDate": "2020-05-30 02:00:00"
"eventDate": "2020-03-14T15:32:42.782Z"
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it for `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`. Both of them work fine.